# Linting Nested Comment Erorr Vue VS Code

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslintrc

Developing a vue application with the eslint-plugin-vue, I am getting the following error when trying to use the comment shortcut in VS code over a template section that contains a nested comment:

> Parsing error: nested-comment. eslint-plugin-vue

Is there a setting in the linter config file that I can change to allow commenting over nested comments or do I need to restart the linter somehow?

[image]

Update: it would appear if I added the following line to my .eslintrc.js file, from this site https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-parsing-error.html#vue-no-parsing-error I should not be seeing this error:

```
   'vue/no-parsing-error': ["error", {
      'nested-comment': false
    }]
```

However, it still remains. I do not have the option to run ESLint restart lint server in my command palette.

Comment: This one? https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/html-comment-indent.html#vue-html-comment-indent

Comment: Do you have a [repro] or a public Github?

Comment: No I do not unfortunately. This is a part of a much larger project. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't ask for a link to the project, but for a repro. Basically replicating the issue in a simpler project just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you do have a `.eslintrc.cjs` file or anything alike, you could probably put that in there

```js
/* eslint-env node */
module.exports = {
  [...],
  rules: {
    'vue/html-comment-indent': 'off',
  },
}
```

`off` is to say that you don't even want to hear about it anytime soon.
Otherwise, you can also use `'warn'`, if you want a warning.

Here is an official reference: https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/html-comment-indent.html#vue-html-comment-indent

Comment: I added this rule to my .eslilntrc.js file and reloaded the window/vs code but it still throws the same error. Do I need to reload it a different way? Is there a different rule that applies to nested comments?

Comment: @supremesector what is the exact name of the rule? `nested-comment` maybe? or `vue/nested-comment`? It should be written when you hover on top of it. Otherwise, you can indeed use `>ESLint: Restart ESlint Server` via the Command Palette of VScode.

Comment: error  Parsing error: nested-comment     vue/no-parsing-error

I edited the original post with a screenshot. I'm trying to shortcut comment the entire <v-row></v-row> block but I get the nested-comment error directly below the top <v-row> on the <v-img> block.

Comment: @supremesector Hm, given your screenshot we can see that the error is more related to `https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-parsing-error.html#vue-no-parsing-error`. So, the rule should be `vue/no-parsing-error`. But it looks like it's not a simple comment but potentially a problem in terms of parsing. If you disable ESlint, does your project work fine? Because it should not give an error here I think. Do you maybe have a [repro] or a public Github?

Comment: I attempted to add the no parsing error but it doesn't seem to work. I'm actually not sure how to disable the ESLint. I updated details above with what I changed. Any ideas?